# Delete all thumbnails for a post

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments

I have a function that sideloads a YouTube thumbnail onto a page... but I want to remove the featured thumb on the page first (and remove all the various auto-generated sizes, too).

I'm assuming I want to use `delete_post_thumbnail()` followed by [`wp_delete_attachment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment) to un-associated the thumb from the post, and then kill the thumb file. Is that correct? And Will that also delete all the various thumb media files (the extra auto-generated sizes) from the disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `wp_delete_attachment( $attachmentid, true )` is **only** thing you need.

Passing `true` as second argument, (`$force_delete` see [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment) ) it:

- remove the thumbnail association with any post
- delete any taxonomy associated to attachment
- and of course remove all the files, also the autogenerated ones

So you do **not** need to also use `delete_post_thumbnail()`.

Comment: Thanks! I have a post ID, so I'm just using: `$existing = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ); if($existing) wp_delete_attachment($existing, true);`

Comment: @Eric you do not need the check. `wp_delete_attachment(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), true);` is enough. If there is no thumbnail `get_post_thumbnail_id` returns an empty string, and passing an empty string to `wp_delete_attachment` as first argument it does nothing and returns an empty string too.